# c#.net importing data table to data model and create entities for getting details for saving updating delete the data

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-6, logic

i created a data model and imported data table to it . then i created a object there and it didnt auto create

```
public MealGroup GrouoMealCode(string GroupmealCode)
 {
  return context.MealGroups.Where(c => c.IsDelete == false && c.MealGroupCode == GroupmealCode).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

here is my code and first i created a table called mealgroup then i imported it to the project . then also i added a class and create a method for creating a statement called GrouoMealCode to get the data from the table

```
 public MealGroup GroupMealCode(string GroupmealCode)
        {
            return context.MealGroups.Where(c => c.IsDelete == false && c.MealGroupCode == GroupmealCode).FirstOrDefault();
        }

    public int SaveGroupMealDetils(MealGroup mealGroup)
    {
        try
        {
            meal = context.MealGroups.Where(c => c.IsDelete == false && c.MealGroupCode == mealGroup.MealGroupCode).FirstOrDefault();
            if (meal == null)
            {
                context.MealGroups.Add(mealGroup);
                context.SaveChanges();
                Return = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                meal.MealGroupCode = mealGroup.MealGroupCode;
                this.context.Entry(meal).State = EntityState.Modified;
                this.context.SaveChanges();
                Return = 2;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Return = 0;
            string Type = "Group Meal  Details Save";
            txt.Exsepotion(Type, ex.ToString());
        }

        return Return;
    }
}
```

}

here is my another code and this doesnot create the entities of the table as auto .please i need to know what is the reason for this and help me pleas e

Comment: When you debug this, what exactly *does* it do and where specifically does it fail?  Why are so many of your variables in a larger scope?  Sharing things like a data context in larger scopes tend to cause problems.

Comment: can you share the details of your `dbcontext` and `connection string` ?